# Python timer stops at random times

Tags: python-3.x

Just a warning, my code uses the pyperclip module but you don't have to pip install it because it is just for cosmetic reasons to make it a little easier. It also reads a file but the contents in the file is not important right now and can be replaced with any file with strings separated by lines.

What I want my code to do is:

WORKING 1. I want to be able to enter in a value for each line in the file, the first number representing hours and the second representing minutes.

NOT WORKING 2. I want to start a timer for for the hours and minutes for each time inputted. After I will add a sound but that is not there yet.

Problem: I input 1 minute for it to count down and it randomly stops in the middle of the count down. I don't know why because sometimes it finishes and sometimes it doesn't.

Code: https://pastebin.com/A2tTHtmK

```
import re
import pyperclip
from collections import OrderedDict
import time
import sys
import winsound

islandAndTimes = {}
fileObject = open("C:\\Users\\harry\\Desktop\\Skyblock Island bossmob warps.txt", "r")
message = fileObject.read()

whatToSearch = re.compile(r'\/is warp \w+')
l1 = whatToSearch.findall(message)

for eachInList in l1:
    pyperclip.copy(eachInList)
    typeIslandTime = input("How long until it spawns? (hours, minutes) ")
    islandAndTimes[eachInList] = typeIslandTime
    newIslandAndTimes = OrderedDict(sorted(islandAndTimes.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
    if typeIslandTime == "0":
        del islandAndTimes[eachInList]
print(newIslandAndTimes)

for everyIsland in newIslandAndTimes:
    for firstKey, firstValue in newIslandAndTimes.items():
        print("\n")
        print(firstKey)
        splitValues = firstValue.split()

        newHours = int(splitValues[0])
        newSecond = 0
        newMins = int(splitValues[1])
        print(newHours, newMins)
        hour = time.strftime("%H")
        minute = time.strftime("%M")

        print("The hour is " + hour + " the minute is " + minute)
        newerHours = newHours + int(hour)
        newerMinute = newMins + int(minute)
        print("total secodns is " + str(int((int(newHours) * 60 * 60) + int(newMins) * 60)-20))
        totalSeconds = int(newHours) * 60 * 60 + int(newMins) * 60-20
        while newSecond != 19:

            time.sleep(1)

            if int(hour) < newerHours or int(minute) < newerMinute:
                #int(hour) > newerHours or int(minute) > newerMinute
                minute = time.strftime("%M")
                hour = time.strftime("%H")
                second = time.strftime("%S")

                sys.stdout.write('\r' + str("Time until ring: " + str(newHours) + " " + str(newMins) + " " + str(newSecond)))
                sys.stdout.flush()
                if newSecond == 0:
                    newSecond = 60
                    newMins = newMins - 1
                elif newMins == 0 and newHours > 0:
                    newHours = newHours - 1
                newSecond = newSecond - 1


print('completed')
```

Comment: Please include your error message or the infinite loop in your result or what the result is and what you expect the result to be.

Comment: There is no error message. I expect the code to end 20 seconds before the time I inputted runs out but it randomly doesnt. Sometimes it will finish without a problem but sometimes it ends early.